# ajax not working with one specific input type

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a form to insert data to database.i used ajax. with a specific button ajax not working
my code 
below code is working code
index.php

```js
$(document).on('click', '#formsubmit', function(e) {

  var data = $("#formjs").serialize();
  $.ajax({

    data: data,
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "post",
    url: "datainsert.php",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.success == "correct") {
        $('#error-msg').hide();
        $('#success-msg').show();
      } else {
        $('#success-msg').hide();
        $('#error-msg').show();
      }

    },

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" action="#" method="post" id="formjs">
  <div class="contct_InputRow form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <label>Your Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control spl_frm_font" required/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contct_InputRow1 form-group">
    <div class="paty_logo">
      <a href="#url"><img src="images/logo1.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="avabl_btn">
      <input style="background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 32px; text-decoration: none; margin: 4px 2px; cursor: pointer;" type="button" name="submit" id="formsubmit" class="button submit" value="Send" />
      <br>

    </div>
    <label for="submit">Send<br>Message</label>
  </div>


  <div class="contct_InputRow1 form-group">
    <div class="paty_logo">
      <a href="#url"><img src="images/logo1.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="avabl_btn">
      <input type='submit' name="submit" id='formsubmit' class="button submit" value='Send' />
      <label for="submit">Send<br>Message</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

is there any issue with this button code.am still confused why its not working

Comment: because submit buttons submit.

Comment: i tried with $('#formjs').on('submit', function(e) { with that,but not got

Comment: because the form submits...

Comment: whats the issue,can you clear it?

Comment: Stop the form from submitting just like the answer states

Comment: when that label coming on button its not working

Comment: well the id is `formsubmit` and the `for` is looking for `submit`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145658/discussion-between-user7441072-and-epascarello).

Answer (score 0):

If you use a real submit input (`type="submit"`), you will need to use `preventDefault()` in your event, as to not submit the form, but instead execute the code inside your event.

If your form is not submittable, you might want to use `type="button"`.

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 0):

**Change Javascritp Like This**

```
function test(){
    var data = $("#formjs").serialize(); $.ajax({ data: data, dataType: "JSON", type: "post", url: "datainsert.php", success: function(data){ if(data.success == "correct"){ $('#error-msg').hide(); $('#success-msg').show(); } else { $('#success-msg').hide(); $('#error-msg').show(); } }, }); }
```

**2.change html like this **

```
<div class="contct_InputRow1 form-group"> <div class="paty_logo"><a href="#url"><img src="images/logo1.png" alt=""/></a></div> <div class="avabl_btn"> <button onClick = 'test()'>send msg </button></div> </div>
```